# delete by custom field in tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

Is there any way to use delete method by custom fields , not by object id , something like

```
curl -v --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X DELETE --data '{"username":"your_username"}' "http://127.0.0.1:8300/api/v1/group/username=EMAIL&api_key=SECRET"
```

not the following

```
curl -v --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X DELETE  "http://127.0.0.1:8300/api/v1/group/obj_id/username=EMAIL&api_key=SECRET"
```

Comment: Could you please improve the formatting of your code.

Comment: All of it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks